# Finding a Lyapunov function for $u''+u'+\sin u = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Now

I need to solve

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} = (1 + \frac{\sin x}{y})\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}$$

Comment: Please: Write $\sin u$, not $sin u$. (See my edit to the question for standard MathJax usage.) $\qquad$

Comment: this is a dissipative system with total energy $E = \frac 12 u'^2 -\cos u$ and $E' = -u'^2$ along the trajectory.

Comment: I am starting to feel like finding the Lyapunov function is a guessing game. Thanks for the answer though.